# How can I get this Javascript to work with multiple links on the same page?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, onclick, mouseevent, hidden

As of right now, I am able to get this javascript function to work with one link.
However, I would like to use the function with multiple links. I have changed `obj` to different values and have also tried using more than one function specified with different values for each to get a working prototype, but nothing seems to work. Below is the javascript function from scratch, no changes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function gObj(obj) {
        var theObj;
        if(document.all){
            if(typeof obj=="string") {
                return document.all(obj);
            }
            else {
                return obj.style;
            }
        }
        if(document.getElementById) {
            if(typeof obj=="string") {
                return document.getElementById(obj);
            }
            else {
                return obj.style;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
</script>
```

And the link code:

```
<div id="axphsh">
<b>Phone:</b><a href="#" onClick="
    gObj('axphsh').style.display='none'; 
    gObj('axphhd').style.display='block'; 
    return false;">Click for Phone Number</a></div>
<div id="axphhd" style="display:none">
<b>Phone:</b> 555-555-5555</div>
```

Ultimately what I want is to use the link code for multiple numbers on the same page, all hidden by default, then unhidden `onClick`. But like I said, this only works for one phone number link, then if there are more specified on the same page, the `onClick` event doesn't work at all. I am thinking it has to do with `getElementById` since div ids for links can be specified in that manner, but I am not completely sure.

Comment: Do all your links have different IDs?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. If you properly format your code, people are more likely to answer your question. Also, on SO signatures and acknowledgements are discouraged, so please don't be offended when yours is removed :)

Answer (score 0):

You should learn some basic JS DOM manipulation.

Why do you even use `document.all` which is not a part of the standard? Use `document.getElementyById` or `document.querySelector`.

If all of your boxes with phone numbers were similar you could go with a more general function:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="phone-link-container">
    <a href="#" class="show-phone-number">Click for phone number</a>
</div>
<div class="phone-number-container">555-555-555</div>
```

**JS**:

```
function showNumber (e) {
  var link = e.target,
    link_container = e.target.parentNode,
    phone_number = link_container.nextElementSibling;

  link_container.style.display = 'none';
  phone_number.style.display = 'block';
}

var numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.show-phone-number');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(numbers, function (el, i) {
  el.addEventListener('click', showNumber);
});
```

It selects all elements with a class `show-phone-number` and binds a function `showNumber` to the `click` event for each of them. This function hides parent of the link (which would be `phone-link-container` in my example) and shows next sibling of the parent (which is `phone-link-container`).

http://jsfiddle.net/9ZF9q/2/

In case your JavaScript code is in `head` you need to wrap all DOM manipulations inside window `load` callback:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  var numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.show-phone-number')
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(numbers, function (el, i) {
    el.addEventListener('click', showNumber);
  });
});
```

You can read more on functions used there on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.nextElementSibling

When it comes to DOM manipulation if you want to keep the compatibility with all older browsers it's easier to use jQuery library - especially if you're a beginner.

Comment: Tried your example, Miszy... and unfortunately, it doesn't work at all. I get the same effect that I get when more than one link is specified with my old code snippet. Granted, your example works on jsfiddle, but not my site. Copied everything over, CSS, HTML, and JS with no luck. Old snippet with 'onClick' event specified still works fine, with one number, but not multiples.

Comment: Where did you place this JavaScript code? If inside `head` then you need to bind it to `loaded` event of the `window` object. See my edit.